# How to use members with "."s

Tags: c++, class, intellisense

I have a question, i want to use my Heap array like "Heap[i].value=x" i have value and Heap array in private and i have in my constructor ,but when i want to use like "Heap[i].value" it says Intellisense "No members available". What should i do, i really stuck. Thanks.

In my header

```
class MPQ
{
private:
    //const int ITEM_NOT_FOUND =-1;
    int value;
    int label;
    int size;
    int Currentsize;
    int *Heap; //heap array
    int*Location;
```

In my cpp my constructor is

```
   MPQ::MPQ(int n)
    {
        value=0;
        label=0;
        size=n;
        Heap=new int [n];
        Location =new int [n];
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            Heap[i]=-1;//ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
            Location[i]=0;
        }
        Currentsize=0;
    }
```

Comment: Heap is an int array. Do you expect a `int i; i.value = 1;` to work? No? Then why do you think it works like this just because there are multiple ints?

Comment: if i make it template does it work?

Comment: So that's really what you want? The you can't use int, but write a custom class type, where you implement `value`.

Comment: or i should make a struct?

Comment: Struct or class doesn't matter, take what you like.

Comment: ok i will try thanks.

Comment: Why is `heap[i].value = ...` better than `heap[i] = ...` ? Why do you need this?

Comment: C++ has arrays of integers, arrays of strings, arrays of almost anything. But it doesn't have an array of nothings. As the author of the code, you know what Heap _should_ contain. Your code is inconsistent. Tell us _in English_ what sort of array Heap whould be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to use my Heap array like "Heap[i].value=x"

In that case, `Heap` cannot be an array of `int` because `int` does not have a member `value`. In fact, `int` does not have any members at all. To be able to use `Heap` like that, it must be an array of such objects that *do* have a member `value`.